# Is there a method to save not missing values in another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a data frame by 20441 rows and 158 columns.
in each row, there are a lot of "NA" values. so I want to convert it to sth like this:

If a value is **not NA**, I save it's row name , column name and value in another data frame.
for example my first data frame is :

| row and column name | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | NA | NA | NA | 5 | 6 |
| r2 | 1 | 3 | NA | NA | NA |

| row name | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | c4 | 5 |
| r1 | c5 | 6 |
| r2 | c1 | 1 |
| r2 | c2 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer using df.melt works but is slower than the below code.
I used %%timeit to measure the time of each code.

df.melt takes 2.47 ms ± 93.5 and
below code takes 314 µs ± 10.4

if performance is not important then df.melt is better since it is a one line code.

```html
row = []
cols = []
val = []
for col in data.columns[1:]: 
    for i,e in enumerate(data[col]): 
        if pd.isna(e) == False:
            row.append(data['row&col name'][i])
            cols.append(col)
            val.append(e)  
new_data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(row,cols,val)),columns=['row','col','val'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `melt`:

```
out = (df.melt('row and column name', var_name='C1', value_name='C2')
         .dropna().astype({'C2': int}))
```

Output:

| row and column name | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| r2 | c1 | 1 |
| r2 | c2 | 3 |
| r1 | c4 | 5 |
| r1 | c5 | 6 |